# List of custom events provided by x-tag library

Tags: x-tag

In the documentation doesn´t seem to be any list of custom events available. Is there any place where I can find out those?

Answer (score 0):

Besides regular javascript events, you can use the following custom events:

```
animationstart
animationend
transitionend
move
enter
leave
scrollwheel
tap
tapstart
tapend
tapmove
taphold
```